Applying chain rule/product rule to $\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \theta(t(\tau)) \, \frac{d}{d\tau} t(\tau) \right)$
How can I apply the chain rule to following function?
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \theta(t(\tau)) \, \frac{d}{d\tau} t(\tau) \right)
$$
The right way to rewrite the above expression is by applying the product rule?
The strange thing is the term $\frac{d}{d\tau} \frac{d}{dt} \theta(t(\tau))$.

EDIT
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right) 
= \frac{d \, \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{d\tau}
= \frac{d \, \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau}
= \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} \, \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)^2
$$
maybe this is true only if $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ is a constant.
Or should I apply the product rule in computing $\frac{d \, \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt}$?
$$
\frac{d \, \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt}
= \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau}
+ \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{d \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt}
$$
So:
$$
\frac{d \, \left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau}
= \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} \, \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)^2
+ \frac{d\theta}{dt} \, \frac{d \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau}
$$

EDIT2:
$$
\frac d{d\tau} \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau))\,\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right) = \frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau))\,\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2} + \frac d{d\tau}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau))\right)\frac{dt}{d\tau}
= \frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau))\,\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2} +
\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}(t(\tau)) \, \frac{dt}{d\tau} \, \frac{dt}{d\tau}
= \frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau))\,\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2} +
\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}(t(\tau)) \, \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)^2
$$

That’s because you’re writing something that has no meaning. You mean $\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}$ evaluated at $t(\tau)$.

@TedShifrin is the right way to write it this one $\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \theta(t) , \frac{d}{d\tau} t(\tau) \right)$? In this case how can I procede? Maybe the result is $\frac{d}{dt} \theta(t) , \frac{d^2}{d\tau^2} t(\tau)$?

Strictly speaking, already $ \frac{d}{dt} \theta(t(\tau))$ could (some might say should) be improved to
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|{t=t(\tau)} \theta(t)= \frac{d}{dt} \theta(t)\Bigg|{t=t(\tau)},.
$$
I think an acceptable notation for this is
$$
\theta'(t(\tau))=(\theta'\circ t)(\tau),.
$$
Now we have something to apply the product rule on:
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau}\Big((\theta'\circ t)(\tau),t'(\tau)\Big),.
$$
Please proceed.

@KurtG. can you see the edit please?

@TedShifrin what I wrote after the edit has a sense?

No. It is not correct, either. Do the product rule first: $$\frac d{d\tau} \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau)),\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right) = \frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau)),\frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2} + \frac d{d\tau}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t(\tau))\right)\frac{dt}{d\tau}.$$ Now use chain rule.

Edit 2 is almost correct, but you need $d^2\theta/dt^2$ in the last term, right? You have to differentiate $d\theta/dt$. But I don't understand your last comment; if $dt/d\tau$ is constant, the last term will still very much be there.

@TedShifrin thank you very much for your help. Could you tell me why it's wrong to apply directly the chain rule as I did in edit1? It seems that the results in edit and edit2 are the same because $$\frac{d \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right)}{dt} , \frac{dt}{d\tau} = d \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right) , \frac{1}{d\tau} = \frac{d^2t}{d\tau^2}$$.

This is essentially your original mistake. You can't differentiate a function of $\tau$ with respect to $t$. ... BTW, you fixed the last line in Edit 2, but not the line before it.

@TedShifrin perfect, now I understood the error!
